# Angularjs mouseover popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How to create a popup while mouse over on a div.

http://jsfiddle.net/akA6H/39/

In this fiddle mouseover popup is working. But while hover on a option name only popup is opend. How to open a popup while hover on a div.

```js
// Code goes here

'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$modal', '$scope', '$log',
    function ($modal, $scope, $log) {
      $scope.option = {
        name: 'Name (hover over for more details)',
        longDescription: 'This is my detailed description...  lots of text here'
      }
       $scope.showOptionDetails = function(option) {
            $log.info($scope.option);
            $scope.optionModal = $modal.open({
                template: '<div class="modal-header" ng-mouseleave="close()"><h3 class="modal-title">Option</h3></div><div class="modal-body">{{option.longDescription}}</div><div class="modal-footer" ng-click="close()">Close</div>',
                controller: 'modalCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    option: function() {
                      return $scope.option;
                    }
                }
            });
       }

        $scope.closeOptionDetails = function() {
            $scope.optionModal.close();
        }
      }
  ]);
  
  myApp.controller('modalCtrl', [
    '$modalInstance', '$scope', '$log', 'option', function ($modalInstance, $scope, $log, option) {
      $log.info(option);
      $scope.option = option;
        $scope.close = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
        }
    }
]);
```

```html
 <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <span ng-mouseover="showOptionDetails(option)" >{{option.name}}</span>  
    </div>
```

Here, I want an empty popup while hover on a div tag. Please help me how can I do this?

Comment: Sorry but cant understood what you are trying to achieve. If all you need to open a empty popup on div hover take a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/B1n9F5X2NNHVaW6JTvC2?p=preview